# Complex formatting error in excel (xlsm) 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm encountering the following error whenever I tried to run my xlsm in excel 2010.

> Complex formatting that is applied to the selected chart may take a
>   while to display. Do you want to continue  using the formatting?"

But my xlsm works fine in excel 2013 and excel 2016.

Please anyone suggest solution to resolve this.

Comment: Can you try saving as `*.xlsx` and try again?

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. Its an macro enabled file. I can't save it in xlsx format..

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the VBA code, try writing the following in the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`:

```
Do
  DoEvents
Loop Until Application.Ready()
```

Source: [From here](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/53tpqa/need_a_way_to_bypass_complex_formatting_error/).